# How to Convert Data Type Varchar to MONEY in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to insert data into my MSSQL server 2000.
The data type of existing field is set as MONEY(19,4).

while I am trying to insert data from PHP. following error occur:

```
Disallowed implicit conversion from data type varchar to data type money. Use the CONVERT function to run this query
```

While trying to CAST my variable as MONEY,

```
 syntax error, unexpected 'AS' (T_AS)
```

While trying to CONVERT, it says

```
Undefined function CONVERT()
```

Please help me sort it out.
Thanks.

Comment: show us how you used your `CAST` and `Convert` functions

Comment: INSERT INTO table (col) VALUES( CAST($amount AS MONEY) )

Comment: CONVERT(MONEY(19,4),@amount) nothing is working. it says, undefined function convert!